# How to get sum of a has_many belongs_to relationship in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have two models.

```
user.rb
-----
has_many :followers

follower.rb
-----
belongs_to :user

field following_id :user_id, type: String
```

I'm trying to find the top 10 users with the most followers.

Ideally it would be something like:

`User.all.order_by(:followers_count)` or something like that.

Anyone have any insight on how to produce that query?

Answer (score 0):

The logical thing to do with a referenced model is to query the "followers" for the following_id of the current user you are looking for:

```
Follower.where( following_id: user_id ).count()
```

Remember that despite the help being given by the ODM to simulate otherwise, all MongoDB queries and operations are only performed on one collection at a time. There is no actual "JOIN" being done on the server, so you most efficiently work your query patterns that way.